# dictionaries or dataframes in one file are not getting updated from another file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a structure as below

```
datastructure.py
dict = {'one' : {'name':'', 'age':''}, 'two':{'name':'', 'age':''}}

update.py
import datastructure as ds
ds.dict['one']['name'] = 'goutham'

validate.py
import datastructure as ds
print(ds.dict['one']['name'])
```

The last line - print(ds.dict['one']['name']) gives the output as ''. It doesn't show the updated value of 'goutham'.

What can be the issue, i have written the code as perfectly as possible by me.

Comment: It looks like you're running these files individually, is that right? In that case, you won't see the changes made in one script from the others.

Comment: yes @mattias. I am running these files individually. Any solution on how i can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `python validate.py`, update.py is never imported so it doesn't affect the rest of the code.

Simply add the line `import update` to the top of validate.py and the print statement prints `goutham`.

Comment: ok, understood your answer. But, what i actually do is run update.py independently and then run validate.py. This is a shorter version of my program, my actual program has a continuous live stream of data which keeps updating the datasetup.py through update.py and i validate the updates through validate.py. So the update.py and validate.py run in parallel all the time.

Will your solution even make the updates available for validate.py?

Comment: You only update the datastructure for the livetime of the program. You can instead write the dictionary to your disk as a json file and then edit that.

Answer (score 0):

your `update.py` have no work, you created a dictionary in `datastructure.py` and then executed `update.py`, this file import that dictionary and changed one value, but you don't saved that value in `datastructure.py`, thus when execution of file `update.py` completed the changed value destroyed, so `datastructure.py` as it is, after that you imported that dictionary in `validate.py` you saw your original dictionary without any changing, if you need to save changing after execution `update.py` add this line in the end of `update.py`

```python
open("datastructure.py", "w").write("dict = " + str(ds.dict))
```

A simple solution:

```python
import update
print(update.ds.dict['one']['name'])
```

Comment: let me try this. Thanks for your response. suppose if i have multiple lines of code that are updating my datastructure.py, should i be adding the above line for every place where this is an update happening?